# apt-get connections time out when updating

Tags: raspbian, apt

i am currently a newbie fro rp2. I am currently facing the problem when i am using putty and vnc server.

When i am going to press sudo apt-get update. It shows this:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get update
0% [Connecting to mirrordirector.raspbian.org (5.153.225.207)] [Connecting to raspberrypi.collabo

Err mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy Release.gpg
Could not connect to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:80 (5.153.225.207), connection timed out

Err raspberrypi.collabora.com wheezy Release.gpg

Could not connect to raspberrypi.collabora.com:80 (46.235.227.226), connection timed out

Err archive.raspberrypi.org wheezy Release.gpg

Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (93.93.130.39), connection timed out [IP: 93.93.130.39 80]

Reading package lists... Done

W: Failed to fetch mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/Release.gpg  

Could not connect to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:80 (5.153.225.207), connection timed out

W: Failed to fetch raspberrypi.collabora.com/dists/wheezy/Release.gpg  

Could not connect to raspberrypi.collabora.com:80 (46.235.227.226), connection timed out

W: Failed to fetch archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/wheezy/Release.gpg 

Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (93.93.130.39), connection timed out [IP: 93.93.130.39 80]

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to RaspberryPi.SE. I've helped you out by formatting your post a little better, I hope you don't mind. You also had a Google Drive link, I think it was for an image? You can upload images directly to your post if you edit it. You mind also find [this useful](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Jivings: The OP can't upload an image, since their rep is less than 10.

Comment: To avoid just giving a +1 response I would also add that a search engine hunt for "Raspberry Pi mirrors" yields a *lot* of old, stale, pre-Wheezy (a general Debian Linux distribution that formed a parent of the Raspbian Raspberry Pi specific "goto" distribution and which shares the same naming scheme for the major version number) - and when I got hit with the same problem with my first use of a Pi a week or so ago it took me a little time to track down a mirror with the current "Jessie" version.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem late last week. It seems that the RPi foundation is having trouble with their mirror director service.  Until they fix the problem, you can get around it by changing your sources file.

1. `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`
2. Change it to

```
    #deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
    #Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
    #deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free`
    deb http://raspbian.mirrors.wvstateu.edu/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
    deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
```

Note: you use whichever mirror you want, that's just the one I selected.

Comment: I also had the same problem and found a working mirror near to me on the following list: https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianMirrors